# Double negation of existential/universal quantifier $\lnot(\exists x(\lnot A(x))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have a (simple) question about the double-negation and existential/universal quantifiers.

When negating the following

$$\lnot\exists x(\lnot A(x)) $$

I believe you just push the negation in (which swaps the quantifier) making it

$$\forall x[\lnot(\lnot A(x))]$$

and then

$$\forall x A(x)$$

Would that be a correct interpretation? Or would I be losing one of the negations on $A(x)$ somewhere earlier?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine. It’s also intuitively clear: the first expression says that there is no $x$ for which $A(x)$ is false, and the last says that $A(x)$ is true for every $x$, clearly the same thing.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Thank you (just read your more detailed answer) - I thought the intuition was clear, but it was part of a larger proof and I was doubting myself as to whether the reduction made sense. I guess I just needed validation.

Answer (score 2):

You did that correctly.

Note that going from

$$\lnot\exists x(\lnot A(x)) $$

to

$$\forall x[\lnot(\lnot A(x))]$$

is an example of 'Quantifier Negation', but going from:

$$\forall x[\lnot(\lnot A(x))]$$

to

$$\forall x A(x)$$

is an instance of 'Double Negation'

Answer (score 1):

A word of caution. Of course at the final step $\forall x\neg\neg Ax$ entails (or at least, classically entails) $\forall x Ax$, and does so because adjacent double negations (classically) cancel each other out.

BUT

The inference is not strictly an application of a standard double negation rule of the form from *$\neg\neg\varphi$ infer $\varphi$*. That rule only allows us to remove *initial* double negations.

SO

To show the entailment in standard proof systems requires a three-step mini-proof:

> $\forall x\neg\neg Ax\quad$ (given)
>
> $ \neg\neg Aa\quad\quad$  (universal instantiation with parameter or free variable depending on system)
>
> $ Aa\quad\quad\quad$  (NOW you can apply the DN rule)
>
> $\forall x Ax\quad\quad$ (universal generalization)

So your reasoning is informally just fine, but do be careful about jumping from $\forall x\neg\neg Ax$ to $\forall x Ax$ *in formal proofs*!

Comment: In a distant course on mathematical logic I remember we talked about (and proved!) a lemma/thm titled roughly like _Lemma for the equivalent replacement_ (I cannot recall any precise formulation thereof), in both propositional and predicate calculus. I did not really understand why we studied that at all as it seemed somewhat tautological, but reading your answer caused it suddenly pop in my head. I feel it encapsulated exactly your argument so that one needs not worry about applying rules in the inside of a formula.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer by Brian M. Scott:

> It’s also intuitively clear: the first expression says that there is
>   no x for which A(x) is false, and the last says that A(x) is true for
>   every x, clearly the same thing.